# No emulation or drawer on my dev tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

[Been looking for the emulation tab for quite a while now and I can't seem to find it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XUTh.png)

Answer (score 3):

I think it's been removed and split up into different places.

It used to show up when you click on the menu button in the console drawer:

[image: console drawer menu]

The sensors section was moved into its own tab:

[image: sensors tab]

It no longer has the "emulate touch screen" option, though. However, if you enter the full device mode touch emulation still exists.

[image: device mode]

If you want to emulate the print view you can do that in the console drawer's Rendering tab:

[image: Rendering tab]

The Network section also exists as a separate tab now:

[image: Network console drawer tab]

Although everything except for setting the user agent can also be done in the normal Network tab.

[image: Normal network tab]

The general device settings like size can be edited in the normal DevTools settings under Devices.

[image: Entering settings from DevTools menu]

[image: Device settings]

Or through the Edit button in the Device Mode menu:

[image: device mode edit devices]

Comment: What about emulation of touch? "Responsive" seems to have it on by default.